# Django static style.css styling

Tags: python-3.x, django, templates, web

I want to share this problem that I got, I made 2 apps in my Django project and one of the apps has a static folder with the file style.css. Everything works but when I try to add a new style let's say I am adding some styling to a div it does not work apparently. Only some of the styles work(older styles) then new ones I try to add it just does not work in templates.

Comment: clear the cache by alt+f5

Comment: clear cache or perform collect static command to update the static files